# PHP SQLite3 - Bind value

Tags: php, sqlite

When I use a sqliteviewer and run:

```
SELECT * FROM areas WHERE x1 <= 1 AND x2 >= 1 AND z1 <= 1 AND z2 >= 1
```

I get the right result, but with this php code I don't get a result:

```
$x = 1;
$z = 1;
$sql = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM areas WHERE x1 <= :x AND x2 >= :x AND z1 <= :z AND z2 >= :z");
$sql->bindValue(':x', $x, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$sql->bindValue(':z', $z, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $sql->execute();
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with this code?

**Edit:**
it works with a query:

```
$result = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM areas WHERE x1 <= ".$x." AND x2 >= ".$x." AND z1 <= ".$z." AND z2 >= ".$z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the query method, you have to use `$result->fetchArray()` to actually get the result. `$sql->execute()` will only return a boolean value of whether the query has succeeded or not.

So the code should look like this:

```
$x = 1;
$z = 1;
$sql = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM areas WHERE x1 <= :x AND x2 >= :x AND z1 <= :z AND z2 >= :z");
$sql->bindValue(':x', $x, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$sql->bindValue(':z', $z, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$boolean = $sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchArray();//This line is important.
```